# get the last element in doctrine2/symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have relation ManyToOne between two entity  Collaborateur and Conge.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Collaborateur", inversedBy="collaborateur", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="collaborateur_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $collaborateur;
```

In my CongeManager i have this function:

```
 public function findCongeByCollaborateur ($collaborateur){
        return $this->getRepository()->findOneBy(array('collaborateur'=>$collaborateur));
    }
```

it return just the first element of Conge i want to get the last one .

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$this->getRepository()->findOneBy(
         array('collaborateur'=>$collaborateur),
         array('id' => 'DESC')
);
```

Comment: This is work on doctrine 2.3 [link](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php)

Comment: wow it works, even if ObjectRepository interface shows 1 parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom entity repository. How to do this can be found on this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

```
public function getLastCongeByCollaborateur($collaborateur) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT conge FROM FullBundleName:Conge conge WHERE collaborateur = :collaborateur ORDER BY conge.id DESC)
        ->setParameter('collaborateur', $collaborateur)
        ->getResult();
}
```

Ordering by id while in descending order will return the last element that is found.